# kafka partitions: does a leader push message to follower or the follower pulls from the leader

Tags: apache-kafka

I had a minor doubt on kafka partitions. Lets say I have kafka configs as follows:

```
replication.factor = 3
min.insync.replicas = 3
replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
acks = all
```

I believe that when the producer sends a message to the broker (partition leader), the leader sends an ack only after the message has been persisted in all the in-sync followers. My doubt here is that

1. will the leader be "pushing" the event to the In-Sync replicas OR
2. will the followers be pulling the event from the leader. If this is the case, how does the leader understand that the event has been pulled by all in-sync followers before giving an ack to the producer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official Apache Kafka [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#replication) results that followers are pulling messages from the Leader.

> Followers consume messages from the leader just as a normal Kafka consumer would and apply them to their own log. Having the followers pull from the leader has the nice property of allowing the follower to naturally batch together log entries they are applying to their log.

The replicas let know the Leader that message is replicated successfully when `min.insync.replicas` count is reached the message get committed .

> We can now more precisely define that a message is considered committed when all replicas in the ISR for that partition have applied it to their log. Only committed messages are ever given out to the consumer.